# Secure--file--priv error in Mysql-Workbench Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I search my problem in the forums and found many solutions but none of them solved this

```
load data infile "/home/marcio/Área de
Trabalho/SQL_Temporario/Insetos/Blastn_1"
into table Blastn_1;
```

I got the following error:

The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

I followed many posts in forums with solutions all around to edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf file and add the line:

```
secure-file-priv = ""
```

I tried to add many variations of this:

```
secure_file_priv= ""
secure_file_priv = ''
secure_file_priv =" "
secure-file-priv= ""
```

and so on ... none worked

I used the command:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

The result was:

```
'secure_file_priv', '/var/lib/mysql-files/'
```

So, i tried to put my files into this directory, and again it did not work.

I need root permission to access this directory, I copied the files into there using 'sudo' as i used the same command to checked if they are there, and it is correct.

It seems that Mysql-workbench is not using the file /etc/mysql/my.cnf, but there is not any other archive with this name in my computer.

I tried to use the command:

```
load data local infile "/home/marcio/Área de
Trabalho/SQL_Temporario/Insetos/Blastn_1"
into table Blastn_1;
```

But the error was that this command (local) is not allowed to MySQL version

Mysql-workbench version 5.7 and Ubuntu is 14.04

I don't know what to do anymore, plz any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.

I've add `secure_file_priv= ""` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
The problem persist.

I've try to move my file into `/var/lib/mysql-files/` (check this directory with `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";`)

But I always have the error :

```
The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

I finally find this solution :

Add : `secure_file_priv= /var/lib/mysql-files/` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: ubuntu 7.10 mysql 5.6 i have same issue but I just removed secure_file_priv=""  from /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf now it'll work without any issue..